# Dynamic parsing of xml attribute key=>value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Is it possible to loop through a set of `<marker>` in an xml document and dynamically access key=>val of attributes and their value of the marker?

```
<marker attr1="val1" attr2="val2" /><marker attrA="vala" attrB="valB" />
```

I want to be able to access attr1, attr2, attrA, attrB and their values with out having to explicitly call those attributes, but rather have it automatically set the key to "attr1" and val as "val1" and so forth.

Comment: One note is <marker> is always consistent as the element.

Comment: What do you mean by "having to explicitly call those attributes"? Can you show us what you are currently doing (what would work), and what syntax you would like to use instead?

Comment: I'm currently using a jQuery plugin that explicitly calls out key=>value pares when parsing the xml: http://paste2.org/CGWemBtp rather than explicitly call out the keys and get the values, I'd like to get all attributes of the marker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.attributes` list:

```
var markers = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("marker");
var map = {};
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
    var ma = markers[i].attributes;
    for (var j=0; j<ma.length; j++) {
        map[ma[j].name] = ma[j].value;
    }
}
// map: {attr1:"val1", attr2:"val2", attrA:"vala", attrB:"valB"}
```

Notice that this seems not to be supported on old IE, but that may only be the case for HTML documents.